# visual studio code remote ssh cant debug python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

so i have been trying all sorts of things to get this working, I am using VS code extension Remote-SSH and I wish to debug server python code, I am able to connect and all that but when I press debug on python extension, the buttons (pause, continue, step over) appears for 2 seconds and the closes, no errors, no messages, nothing, I suppose it's python extension problem, not vs code. Not sure what info I can provide to you guys. If there are some other ways to debug server python code I am open to suggestions, thank you.

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint to cause the debugger to pause?

Comment: yes I did, thanks for suggestion. I solved this using ptvsd and ssh tunneling